# Localization of wordpress: Date and Time

Tags: wordpress, localization

I am creating a blog site in Bangla language. I am using a localization file called `bn_BD.mo` for this pupose. It translates the whole site but the date and time remains english. Actually I am not getting the numbers converted to Bangla Language. I know the mo file will not help in these cases.

So I have extended my `function.php` file of the theme folder with following function

```
function make_bangla_number($str)
{
    $engNumber = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0);
    $bangNumber = array('১','২','৩','৪','৫','৬','৭','৮','৯','০');
    $converted = str_replace($engNumber, $bangNumber, $str);

    return $converted;
}

add_filter( 'get_the_time', 'make_bangla_number' );
add_filter( 'the_date', 'make_bangla_number' );
add_filter( 'get_the_date', 'make_bangla_number' );
add_filter( 'comments_number', 'make_bangla_number' );
add_filter( 'get_comment_date', 'make_bangla_number' );
add_filter( 'get_comment_time', 'make_bangla_number' );
```

It converts the date of the every post. But my pagination numbers and archive remains same like following

`জানুয়ারী 2012` which is translation of `January 2012`
`ফেব্রুয়ারী 2012` which is translation of `February 2012`.

And the pagination looks like

`পাতা 1 2 3 4 5 6` which is translation `Page 1 2 3 4 5 6`
But I want it to be in bangla digits like following.

`পাতা ১ ২ ৩ ৪ ৫ ৬`.

What should I do? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Follow the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12970310/how-to-localize-the-number-of-wordpress-post-views)

Answer (score 0):

Would an preg replace not work for this?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the Wordpress APIs where possible, so try using the [date_i18n](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/date_i18n) function.