# how to localize the number of wordpress post views?

Tags: localization, wordpress, indic

I want to display post view in localize number. I add these function in function.php to do so

```
function make_bangla_number($str)
{
    $engNumber = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0);
    $bangNumber = array('à§§','à§¨','à§©','à§ª','à§«','à§¬','à§­','à§®','à§¯','à§¦');
    $converted = str_replace($engNumber, $bangNumber, $str);

    return $converted;
}

add_filter( 'the_views', 'make_bangla_number' );
```

But I am unable to show the number in localize. Whenever i call the_views it shows the english number. Any idea how to show the post view number in localize language?

For further info here is my post view function:

```
// function to count post views.
function setPostViews($postID) {
    $count_key = 'views';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        $count = 0;
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
    }else{
        $count++;
        update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);
    }
}
// function to display number of post views.
function the_views($postID){
    $count_key = 'views';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
        return "0 View";
    }
    return $count.' à¦¬à¦¾à¦°';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parvez,

There is support available for Bangla Language in WordPress, please refer [http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_in_Your_Language#Bangla_-*Bengali*.28bn_BD.29](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_in_Your_Language#Bangla_-_Bengali_.28bn_BD.29)

You must required to install Bangla Language Pack to your WordPress, which you can found from below links...

http://svn.automattic.com/wordpress-i18n/bn_BD/trunk/messages/

http://www.shadhinbangla.com/wordpress-bangla-language-pack-beta-3/2011/10/

Also, you must check CHARSET must set to UTF-8 in your HTML code and your MySQL DB must be create with Collation CHARSET UTF-8 to store Bangla value in DB.

Also I found one old WordPress Plugin to show Date & Time in Bangla, you can refer their code also to solve your problem. Here is plugin link...
  http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/bangla-numbers-in-date-and-time/

Or you can ask for help to WordPress Support team.

Hey, I recently found detailed draft to setup Bangla Language in WordPress, please refer this link...
http://www.lavluda.com/2008/11/08/wordpress-with-full-bangla-language-support/

Comment: I have Bangla language pack installed and my site CHARSET is also UTF-8. Bangla language pack does all but can't convert the English number into bangla number. So I using that code. With that i can convert the date number in Bangla but unable to convert the views. So I am here.

Comment: @pervez have you check code of this plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/bangla-numbers-in-date-and-time/

As I see they did little tweak to display numbers, Please refer Installation Tab on this plugin, they mentioned to load Bangla Numbers...

"Upload Bangla Numbers in Date and Time.zip to the /wp-content/plugins/ directory and extract the zipped file."

Comment: yes. but that plugin convert the_date bangla numbers only. But I wanted to convert the views count number into bangla. So i add the filter add_filter( 'the_views', 'make_bangla_number' );
in function.php but its not working.

Comment: @pervez Have you updated wp-config.php with below mentioned parameters for language.

replace define (‘WPLANG’, ”); with define (‘WPLANG’, ‘bn_BD’);

Comment: @pervez can you share your site link to check

Comment: Sure, here is my site: http://www.primenews24.com and I updated wp-config.php with those given parameters.